# Why did Machinima make Mortal Kombat: Legacy viewing private on YouTube?

Tags: distribution, mortal-kombat-legacy

Machinima released *Mortal Kombat: Legacy* seasons 1 and 2 on their YouTube channel exclusively and received quite favorable reviews from fans and critics. But I recently noticed that they made all the episodes from seasons 1 & 2 private. Only the behind-the-scenes video is still available for viewing. Why did Machinima do this? Why did they remove their most famous web-series from public viewing?

Comment: May be they are planning to make money now

Comment: @Panther Asked the same on [twitter too](https://twitter.com/Ankit_Om_Sharma/status/813035721481076737). Maybe I should ping more people ;)

Comment: Retweeted from my handle https://twitter.com/sourabh9776

Comment: Tweeted to few more [people](https://twitter.com/Ankit_Om_Sharma/status/813039370043150340). Done for my tweeter quota for a month :D

Comment: Probably they received a legal notice of some sort.

Comment: @OrangeDog legal notice for what? It's there content only.

Comment: The original game assets they're using? Any additional music or other graphics perhaps?

Comment: @OrangeDog didn't WB greenlight them for 3rd season?

Comment: At the moment, the videos are still available to view on Steam.